# Why I lose the :hover color of an anchor when setting the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using JQuery to hilight an "icon" of an icon bar, but when I set the `background` property I lose the :hover color hilighting, i.e. if I set a yellow background it remains yellow.

I want to be able to programmatically change the color of the icon but having the icon color to change to darkgrey when the mouse is over it (I'd like to do the first thing with jquery and the second with css)

Can you help me?

```js
$("#myId").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```css
.icon-bar {
 z-index: 9999999999;
    width: 336px; 
    background-color: #EFEFEF; 
    overflow: auto; 
}

.icon-bar a {
    float: left; 
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px; 
    padding: 6px 0; 
    transition: all 0.3s ease; 
    color: navy;
    border-left: 1px solid navy;
    border-right: 1px solid navy;
    font-size: 20px; 
}


.icon-bar a:hover {
    background-color: darkgrey;
}

.active {
    background-color: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="icon-bar">
   <a id="myId"  href="#">A</a>
</div>
```

Comment: jquery add inline style that are more specific .. .add a class instead

Comment: can you make an example?

Comment: you already have the active class. so simply add this class using jQuery .. and pay attention to specificity of your selectors (like explained in the duplicate)

Comment: thank you, I fixed using addClass removeClass